# How to dynamically loading Google Tag Manager ID on index.html for different environments in a single page application with Vue.js and asp.net core

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement google analyics 4 on a single page application website with Vue.js and asp.net core.
I would like to dynamically update the google tag manager ID ('GTM-XXXX') of google analyics script on index.html for different environment such as Localhost or Dev or Production when the app is running. The script is provided by Google's instruction below which added to the index.html so that it is not hardcoded.  What is the best solution to do this?
Note: I can put the google tag manager ID on the appsettings.local.json file like a regular website but don't know how to access it from the index.html for a Single Page App   website.

Note: the script is from google analytics instructions
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web

Copy the following JavaScript and paste it as close to the opening tag as possible on every page of your website, replacing GTM-XXXX with your container ID:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Copy the following snippet and paste it immediately after the opening tag on every page of your website, replacing GTM-XXXX with your container ID:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I could not find any package that allowed to set gtm id after Vue started. So to solve the problem what i did was:

1. Extract the gtm function into my methods in App.vue;
2. Call the function, passing the loaded gtm id;

   ```
    created() {
        this.enableGoogleAnalytics();
    },
    methods: {
        async enableGoogleAnalytics(){
            var googleAnalyticsId = await loadGtmId(); // GTM-XXXXXXX
            this.activateGtm(window,document,'script','dataLayer',googleAnalyticsId);
        },

        activateGtm(w,d,s,l,i){
            w[l]=w[l]||[];
            w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
            var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
            j.async=true;
            j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        },
   }
   ```