# Can I insert a Google tag manager <script> dynamically via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, google-tag-manager

So I have an multi tenancy application written in VueJS and I need to insert these pixels based on what are stored in our database as a string.

The google tag manager script on database is only for showing. In production the XXXX is replaced to the actual ID

[image: database printscreen showing the code]

I've already tried this way:

```js
// client being the database info.
     
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", client.customScripts);
```

It shows on HTML but it doesn't recognize the pixel ID on Google Tag Assitant.

Comment: This piece of code that I tried is being callend in App.vue, where it mounts the entire application and populate the client information

Comment: Have you tried `eval(client.customScripts);`?

Comment: Try the strategy [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70712451/6225326)

Comment: @LajosArpad it returns ` Unexpected token '<' `.  I need to inject this whole string where it can have one or more scripts into the head tag. 

So it can be like:

"
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script>someFunctionHere();<script>
"

And when the page is loaded it would have those two script running

Comment: @yoduh yeah it would solve the google tag manager, but what if our clients want to add  other scripts such as meta pixels instead, or any other script. I would have to abstract each possibility into custom functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
document.head.innerHTML = client.customScripts + document.head.innerHTML;
```

but this is a very hacky solution. You might want to review why you want to do this via Javascript instead.

Comment: This gives the same effect in the solution that I tried. It show on html but the tag manager dont recognize the pixel